# Should 3.4 enums use UPPER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, python-3.4

As the documentation says, an enumeration is a set of symbolic names (members) bound to unique, **constant** values. The [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants) says that constants are usually named as `UPPER_CASE`, should I use this notation in Python 3.4 [enums](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html)? If yes, why the examples in the docs are using `lower_case`?

Comment: In languages that support enumerations as first class citizens, Enumerations != Constants. Yes, the enumeration members may have constant values, but that's not the same as a variable being a constant.

Comment: FWIW, there are lots of PEP8 infractions in the standard lib ... And the whole thing is meant to be a *guide* anyway.  One of the most important parts of it is knowing when to bend/break the rules.  IMHO, this is a bit of a corner case and I wouldn't fault you for going either way.  Just be consistent.

Comment: @mgilson One of the problems treating PEP8 merely as a guide that you might bend or break are that it means that there's a lot more room for bikeshedding on style issues. When I'm reviewing someone's code, and I come across a patch which upcases something because the author thinks that it counts as a constant while I disagree, then that turns into a whole long pointless email thread (this actually came up recently as someone upcased a global logger because Pylint complained about it). It's nice to have an authoritative, easy to apply rule to avoid this kind of bikeshedding.

Comment: @BrianCampbell -- [I'm not saying anything novel here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds).  All I'm saying is that as far as I see it, depending on your interpretation of what is and isn't a constant, two different people could come to different judgments about what to do here.  *On a project basis*, sometimes it's necessary to adopt additional style rules.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Update**

The BDFL (Benevolent Dictator For Life) [has spoken](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2016-September/042340.html), and the [`Enum documentation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum) has changed to reflect all upper-case member names.

---

The examples in the [previous] docs are lower-case primarily because one of the preexisting modules that Enum was based on used lower-case (or at least its author did ;).

My usage of enum has usually been something along the lines of:

```
class SomeEnum(Enum):
    ... = 1
    ... = 2
    ... = 3
globals().update(SomeEnum.__members__)
```

which effectively puts all the members in the module namespace.

So I would say whichever style feels more comfortable to you -- but pick a style and be consistent.

Comment: Mmm I don't like using enums like that but it's just my opinion. I think I'll use `lower_case`. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: What is the purpose of "globals().update(SomeEnum.__members__)"? SomeEnum is already in the modules namespace so what exactly is that line achieving?

Comment: @variable: it's putting the members themselves in the module namespace -- so instead of `SomeEnum.SOME_MEMBER` you can just type `SOME_MEMBER`.

Answer (score 8):

I think they're not UPPER_CASE because, well, it just looks weird when it is.  Since you can only access the enumerations through the class (e.g. `my_enum.VALUE`) it looks weird if the members are capitalized.  In C the members of the enumeration go into the module namespace, so it doesn't look weird (to me) when the members are capitalized, in usage:

```
typedef enum {OFF, ON} lightswitch;
lightswitch bathroomLight = ON;
```

But in Python you access them through the enumeration class that you create, and it looks weird to go from ClassStyle names to ALL_CAPS.

```
class Lightswitch(Enum):
    OFF = 0
    ON = 1

# isn't that weird?
my_light = Lightswitch.OFF
```

Bottom line, I think it's just aesthetic.  I've been wrong before, though, and I realize that this is just my opinion.

Comment: Well, it’s not weirder than, say, `re.IGNORECASE`. (I don’t find it weird at all, really, but that’s subjective.)

Comment: @minitech  You are right; it really is subjective.  Maybe the difference is that `re.IGNORECASE` is a module level constant, and the enum's member's look more like class attributes.

Comment: Definitely it's subjective, I like the `lowercase.UPPER_CAS`E notation. But I think I'll use `lower_case` just like in the docs. Thanks! +1

Comment: Lightswitch.OFF is actually preffered way in Java so people comming form Java might see that as less weird that the lowercase.

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt about style, I usually defer to the style used in standard library code and examples from the official documentation. It keeps me from wasting time on arbitrary decisions.

So in this case, I recommend lower case, like variable names.

Comment: Well I'll accept this but there's no right answer, all answers are good and it depends on the programmer. Thanks.

Comment: The BDFL (Benevolent Dictator For Life) has spoken, and the [`Enum documentation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum) has changed to reflect all upper-case member names.