# Call an IntEnum class from inside a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I have an example IntEnum class:

```
class ShapeMethod(IntEnum):
    NONE = 0
    circle = 1
    square = 2
```

That needs to be called by the `__init__` function of another class:

```
class ExampleClass():
    def __init__(look_at_shapes=None):
        """
        Args:
            look_at_shapes (dict): A dictionary of shape inputs.
        """
        if look_at_shapes:
            self.shape = ShapeMethod.NONE
            if look_at_shapes["colour"]:
                self.colour = look_at_shapes["colour"]

    def do_something_with_shape:
        if self.shape == ShapeMethod.circle:
            print('awesome you got a circle'.)
        elif self.shape == ShapeMethod.square:
            print('squares have 4 sides.')
        else:
            print('nothing to see here.')
```

where, the `self.shape` attribute needs to be `circle`, `square` or `NONE`.

The `do_something_with_shape` function would then be called by:

```
input = {"colour" = blue}
my_object = ExampleClass(look_at_shape=input)
my_object.do_something_with_shape
```

The structure of `input` needs to be a dictionary, and it is reasonably simple to set the `colour`. However, I do not know how to properly use the `IntEnum` class from inside a dictionary. For example, if I want to print `squares have 4 sides.`

Note: Do all options in `ShapeMethod(IntEnum)` need to be capitalized?

---

What I have looked at so far:

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) for Python gives a number of examples; however, none fit my exact case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to use would be the following:

```py
from enum import IntEnum


class ShapeMethod(IntEnum):

    NONE = 0
    circle = 1
    square = 2


class ExampleClass:

    def __init__(self, look_at_shapes=None):
        """
        Args:
            look_at_shapes (dict): A dictionary of shape inputs.
        """
        
        self.shape = None
        self.colour = None

        if look_at_shapes:
            if look_at_shapes[ShapeMethod]:
                self.shape = look_at_shapes[ShapeMethod]

            if look_at_shapes["colour"]:
                self.colour = look_at_shapes["colour"]


    def do_something_with_shape(self):
        if self.shape is ShapeMethod.NONE:
            print('awesome you got a circle.')
        elif self.shape is ShapeMethod.square:
            print('squares have 4 sides.')
        else:
            print('nothing to see here.')


input_var = {
    "colour": 'blue',
    ShapeMethod: ShapeMethod.square
}
my_object = ExampleClass(look_at_shapes=input_var)

my_object.do_something_with_shape()
```

Regarding your side question:

> Note: Do all options in `ShapeMethod(IntEnum)` need to be capitalized?

It's entierly up to you. They can be all upper-case, which is in acordance with PEP 8 since they'll be constants. However, a lot of folks decide to capitalize only the first letter and it's a valid choice of style. The least common option is using all lower-case or mixing different capitalizations, however there is nothing stopping you from doing so.
[See this answer for a complete reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21359677/)

Comment: Your `__init__` leaves `shape` and `colour` undefined if `look_at_shapes` is `None`.

Comment: @EthanFurman thank you for the reminder, I revised it. One of the reasons I like Python is because I can leave instance members undefined :) It's so terribly frustrating having to declare instances variables as None in compiled languages.

Answer (score 3):

```
input = {
        "shape": ShapeMethod.square,
        "colour": "blue",
        }


def __init__(look_at_shapes=None):
    """
    Args:
        look_at_shapes (dict): A dictionary of shape inputs.
    """
    look_at_shapes = look_at_shapes or {}
    self.shape = look_at_shapes.get("shape", ShapeMethod.NONE)
    self.colour = look_at_shapes.get("colour")  # None if "colour" doesn't exist

    def do_something_with_shape:
        if self.shape == ShapeMethod.circle:
            print('awesome you got a circle'.)
        elif self.shape == ShapeMethod.square:
            print('squares have 4 sides.')
        else:
            print('nothing to see here.')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check `self.shape.value` insead of `self.shape` when you're looking to check the underlying string in the enum class.

```
if self.shape.value == 'circle':
```

Or

```
if self.shape == ShapeMethod.circle
```

Comment: thank you. That is super useful as I hadn't noticed that error; however, I was wondering more about how to set the value from the `input` dictionary. If you know, that would be great :)